# jQuery - get style element attached to other class

Tags: jquery, html, css

One of my div's is: `<div class="wpb_div vcdiv_123124814"></div>`

To .vcdiv_123124814 is a background-image set (in CSS). But the number is on every page unique. I would like to get the background-image in jQuery / javascript var, but by tagging .wpb_div.

How is this possible?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var bgImage = jQuery('.wpb_div').css('background-image');
});
</script>
```

Comment: Your code seems to right, what error you got ? are you able to get the url of image ? try to print bgImage using `console.log(bgImage)`

Comment: I got undefined.

Comment: Try with `jQuery(window).load(function(){// your code })` may it will not getting on document ready.

Comment: That works, thnx!

Answer (score 0):

Set CSS property like this,
`jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var bgImage = jQuery('.wpb_div').css('background-image','src_here');
});`.
You are only getting the background in your code, give another parameter to set it. Like above

Comment: I would like to _GET_ the bg-image url that is set in CSS to the unique class.